# Getting the query, key and value matrices from PyTorch with self_attn.in_proj_weight

Tags: pytorch, tensor, transformer-model

We have implemented a transformer based on the tutorial [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transformer_tutorial.html).

We need to access the weights of the query, key and value matrices and were planning on doing this with `model.state_dict()`. However the model stores these matrices as a concatenation in this shared matrix.

```
model.state_dict()['transformer_encoder.layers.0.self_attn.in_proj_weight']
```

We would assume that they are concatenated in the order query, key, value. If so we can just split the tensor manually. However, we were unable to verify in the PyTorch documentation whether this is the actual order. Is there an easy way to verify whether this is the case? Or any other way to get the query, key and value matrices individually for this transformer model?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of MultiHeadAttention in the pytorch codebase follows a simple [check](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/021d2676941976d6a35a3b0e2034238889a6c872/torch/nn/modules/activation.py#L959-L976):

```py
if not self._qkv_same_embed_dim:
            self.q_proj_weight = Parameter(torch.empty((embed_dim, embed_dim), **factory_kwargs), requires_grad = not self.freeze_proj_mat['q'])
            self.k_proj_weight = Parameter(torch.empty((embed_dim, self.kdim), **factory_kwargs), requires_grad = not self.freeze_proj_mat['k'])
            self.v_proj_weight = Parameter(torch.empty((embed_dim, self.vdim), **factory_kwargs), requires_grad = not self.freeze_proj_mat['v'])
            self.register_parameter('in_proj_weight', None)
else:
            self.in_proj_weight = Parameter(torch.empty((3 * embed_dim, embed_dim), **factory_kwargs))
            self.register_parameter('q_proj_weight', None)
            self.register_parameter('k_proj_weight', None)
            self.register_parameter('v_proj_weight', None)
```

where,

```py
self._qkv_same_embed_dim = self.kdim == embed_dim and self.vdim == embed_dim
```

Here, `kdim, embed_dim, vdim` all have their usual meanings as per the function definition, check [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html#torch.nn.MultiheadAttention).

This is an implementation detail that is abstracted away from the user. But as you mentioned, to get access to the `Q, K, V` matrices when `self._qkv_same_embed_dim` is `True`, you can extract this Tensor and call the method `_in_projection_packed` that is available in the `nn.functional` [API source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/82401c6a69e0029828ee75cf7ab94abd24728963/torch/nn/functional.py#L4727-L4787).

You can check all the provided links to these function implementations for your reference.

---

#### TLDR

You can use the [`torch.split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html#torch.split) function to split the projection weights into query, key and value matrices. Like this,

```py
in_proj_weight = model.state_dict()['transformer_encoder.layers.0.self_attn.in_proj_weight']
q, k, v = torch.split(in_proj_weight, [embed_dim, embed_dim, embed_dim])
```

Hope this helps.